# Parallel Looping with nested recursive for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, recursion, parallel-processing

Parallel Looping.

Hi there, I am having trouble figuring out what kind of loop I should be using for a section of my code. 
my issue it that I would like to run the program with multiple initial conditions.for example lets say I have a matrix q where its dimensions are 4 by 2. q(:,1) is the first set of initial conditions and q(:,2) is the second set of initial conditions.
what I want is the recursive for loop (lines 11-22) to take the independent initial conditions q(:,1) and q(:,2) and simultaneously run them through the for loop independently. 
Here is some mock code (unfortunately I cannot use the actual code due to an NDA):

```
1   p=ones(3,2); %initial condition
2   q=2.*ones(4,2); %initial condition
3   r=3.*ones(3,2); %initial condition

4   k=1;     %here i want it to iterate for k=1:2 in parallel (i think)
5   pp=p(:,k);
6   qq=q(:,k);
7   rr=r(:,k);

8   p=p(:,k);
9   q=q(:,k);
10  r=r(:,k); %for loop below requires vector form.

11      for t=0:.5:60
12          v=[p;q;r];  %initial conditions for ode45
13          tspan=[t,t+.25,t+.5];
14          [T,Y]=ode45('somefunc',tspan,v,...);
15          v=Y(3,:);
16          p=v(1:3);
17          q=v(4:7);
18          r=v(8:10);

   %building up a matrix with all the data from the iterated/recursive ode45
19          pp=cat(2,pp,p); 
20          qq=cat(2,qq,q);
21          rr=cat(2,rr,r);
22      end
```

The code above evaluates for only k=1 or k=2. it does not iterate k=1:2.
what I want is to end up with a multi-dimensional array for pp, qq and rr for the two (at some point n) possible initial conditions. ie pp(:,:,1) would be the matrix with the first initial conditions and pp(:,:,2) would be the second initial conditions. same goes for qq and rr.

This is why I think I need a parallel for loop instead? so that the initial conditions in lines 1 through 3 can be called again rather than the redefined values of my variables due to the for loop in lines 11-22.
I am also confused on how to satisfy parfor's requirement of independent iterations while having a nested for loop with dependent iterations within.

Please let me know if there is anything else you would like me to explain further or clarify.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: 1. Recursion is not what you say it is. 2. There are too many words in your post - post minimal text introducing what you want, and then show what you tried. Most of this text is only clutter and will drive away potential solution givers.

Comment: Thank you for the notes on amount of the text. When you say recursion is not what I say it is, what do you mean.